# Cannot split string separated by two new lines

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to split a string separated by two lines such as:

```
world
hello
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
System.out.print("Please input a String: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
String[] letters = input.split("\\r?\\n");
```

My output just outputs the first string and does not split the string how I want it to.  I've tried a couple of other different regex operations such as `\s+` and `\\n\\n` but none seem to work.

Comment: `nextLine` reads *one* line at a time. Which means that in your case there are not line breaks in `input` so splitting on them can't happen. If you want to read two lines use `nextLine` twice or until scanner `hasNextLine()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `in.nextLine()` which reads a complete line. So it is only reading the first string.
I don't know which reader you are using, better use something which reads all the lines and then make use of split using newLine(\n) character to get the desired result.

Comment: thanks for the response I do not know how I didn't see that was the problem.  I ended up just throwing the multiline string into a text file and reading it from there using a simple method to then insert into a string.